# VPN connection results in extremely slow connection (OpenVPN)

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am currently in the and connecting to a research institute in India using OpenVPN. The client config file says I am using `TCP`, however, I tried with `UDP` too.

My issue is that my connection is seriously degraded to about 1 Mbps when I connect to the VPN (see speedtest results below). Please suggest if there are any ways to improve the same. I have read that many people have had this problem and there is no single solution that can solve it. I tried suggestions from various posts, like https://serverfault.com/questions/686286/very-low-tcp-openvpn-throughput-100mbit-port-low-cpu-utilization, to change the buffer size and `txqueuelen`. I had also set

```
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
```

and with `txqueuelen = 4000` but there was no improvement in the connection speed (have also tried other combinations of these variables). `MTU` is set to 1500.

The server uses CentOS 7 and I am using Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. The version on OpenVPN that I am using: OpenVPN 2.5.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.

(I am new to the technicalities of VPN even though I have used it before.)

Speedtest without VPN:

```
Testing from University of <hidden> ...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by Bresco Broadband (Columbus, OH) [263.97 km]: 23.339 ms
Testing download speed..........................................
Download: 542.38 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed............................................
Upload: 611.33 Mbit/s
```

Speedtest with VPN:

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from <hidden> Communications (<hidden IP address>)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by BBNL (Bangalore) [2.23 km]: 649.717 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 0.96 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed................................................................................................
Upload: 2.19 Mbit/s
```

OpenVPN client config file:

```
dev tun
proto TCP
persist-tun
persist-key
cipher AES-256-CBC
ncp-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM
auth SHA1
tls-client
client
resolv-retry infinite
remote <hidden> 443 tcp
verify-x509-name "<hidden>-VPN" name
auth-user-pass
pkcs12 pfSense-TCP4-443-<username hidden>.p12
tls-auth pfSense-TCP4-443-<username hidden>-tls.key 1
remote-cert-tls server
sndbuf 512000
rcvbuf 512000
txqueuelen 1000
```

Comment: You are connecting to a VPN literally on the other side of the world. Each packet you send will be routed there and then to wherever it needs to go, and there is no indication here that the VPN provider does actually have a decent connection speed to the places you need to reach. I would say this is probably expected

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find [this link](https://support.untangle.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034773434-Why-are-connections-so-slow-over-OpenVPN-) that explains why this may be the case and offers a possible solution. Here is a [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/VPN/comments/8gjndv/openvpn_and_slow_speeds/) that offers a few more solutions in the comments. However, as I was researching I found that this is a [common issue with OpenVPN](https://www.google.com/search?q=open+vpn+slow&client=safari&channel=iphone_bm&source=hp&ei=qaPhYte5CfuF0PEPuqiI8Ag&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYuGxuVkBc43-b61NT5izERghuzlRTSY4&ved=0ahUKEwiXso_c95n5AhX7AjQIHToUAo4Q4dUDCAw&uact=5&oq=open+vpn+slow&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEIAEMgQIABAKMgQIABAKMgQIABAKMgQIABAKMgQIABAKMgQIABAKMgQIABAKMgQIABAKMgQIABAKOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToICC4QsQMQgwE6DgguEIAEELEDEMcBENEDOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAzoICC4QjwEQ6gI6CAgAEI8BEOoCOggIABCxAxCDAToICC4QgAQQ1AI6CwguEIAEELEDENQCOg4ILhCABBCxAxCDARDUAjoICAAQgAQQsQM6DgguELEDEIMBEMcBENEDOggIABCABBDJAzoLCC4QgAQQxwEQ0QM6DQguEIAEEMcBENEDEAo6EwguEIAEELEDEIMBEMcBENEDEAo6BQguEIAEOgcIABCABBAKUABYkBdgtRhoAXAAeACAAUiIAasGkgECMTSYAQCgAQGwAQo&sclient=gws-wiz) (many articles/threads discussing that it slows down or it has speed issues)